# Find how many real positive numbers, a, b, c, exist, such that they form an ordered pair (a,b,c), satisfying the following equations.

Tags: linear-algebra

The equations are:
$ [a]bc =3 $,
$ a[b]c = 4 $,
$ ab[c] = 5 $,
I tried to assume limits of values of a,b, and c, but it is not working... 
Neither is working the division or multiplication of things...
Please help

Comment: Do you take $[a]$ to mean the floor of $a$?

Comment: [x]= the Greatest Integer Function of x.

Comment: To get started:  Note that none of them can be in the half open interval $[0,1)$.  Thus, if $\lfloor a \rfloor>3$ the first equation is impossible.  If $\lfloor a \rfloor=3$ then $b=c=1$ (which contradicts the second equation) and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that $[a][b][c] \leq [a]bc = 3$, and none of $[a],[b],[c]$ can be zero. Thus $[a][b][c] \in \{1,2,3\}$. So the only possibilities are

- All of $[a],[b],[c]$ are $1$
- Two of them are $1$ and one of them is $2$
- Two of them are $1$ and one of them is $3$.

Consider cases based on the value of $[a]$. If $[a]=3$, then the first equation implies $bc=1$. But since $b,c \geq 1$, in fact $b=c=1$. But then the second equation implies $a=4$, a contradiction.

If $[a]=2$, then the first equation implies $bc= \frac{3}{2}$. Since $b,c \geq 1$, we have $b \leq bc = \frac{3}{2}$ and $c \leq bc = \frac{3}{2}$. Thus $[b]=[c]=1$. Then the third equation implies $ab=5$, yet we know $a <3$ (since $[a]=2$) and $b \leq \frac{3}{2}$, so this is impossible.

The the only possibility is $[a]=1$. From the bullet points above, we know at least one of $[b]$ or $[c]$ must also be $1$. We also know $bc=3$ from the first equation.

Say we have $[a]=[b]=1$. The second equation implies $ac=4$, and since $a<2$ we have $c>2$. The first equation implies $bc=3$. Dividing $ac$ by $bc$, we have $a/b=ac/bc=4/3$. So equation $3$ becomes
$$ \frac{4}{3}b^2[c]=5.$$
If $[c]=2$, then this implies $b^2=15/8$, so $b=\sqrt{15/8}$, $a= \frac{4}{3}\sqrt{15/8}$, and $c=\sqrt{24/5}$. If $[c]=3$, then this implies $b^2=\frac{5}{4}$, so $b=\sqrt{5/4}$, $a = \frac{4}{3}\sqrt{5/4}$, and $c=3/\sqrt{5/4}<3$, a contradiction.

If instead we have $[a]=[c]=1$, then the third equation implies $ab=5$, and since $a<2$ we have $b>5/2$. The first equation also implies $bc=3$. Dividing $ab$ by $bc$, we have $a/c=ab/bc = 5/3$. So the second equation becomes
$$\frac{5}{3}c^2[b]=4.$$
If $[b]=2$, this implies $c^2 = \frac{6}{5}$, so $c=\sqrt{6/5}$, $a = \frac{5}{3}\sqrt{6/5}$, and $b = \sqrt{15/2}$. If instead $[b]=3$, then this implies $c^2 = \frac{4}{5}$, but then $c<1$, a contradiction.

So there are two solutions:

- $a=\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{\frac{15}{8}} = \sqrt{\frac{10}{3}}$
- $b =\sqrt{15}{8}=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{15}{2}}$
- $c= \sqrt{\frac{24}{5}}=2\sqrt{\frac{6}{5}}$

and

- $a = \frac{5}{3}\sqrt{\frac{6}{5}}=\sqrt{\frac{10}{3}}$
- $b= \sqrt{\frac{15}{2}}$
- $c = \sqrt{\frac{6}{5}}$